# How can we find the polarity of dc motor and why we connect motor with thick wire?

Tags: motor, dc

DC MOTOR 
How can we find the polarity of dc motor before connection ? Why we connect thick wire with armature winding ? Internal winding wire diameter is very thin in compresion to external wire by which we connect supply to the motor. And alsi why we connect thin wire with field winding ?

Answer (score 2):

**Polarity**

DC motors can usually run with either polarity but direction of rotation will be reversed. Read the data sheet or the label on the motor if you need to be sure it will turn the right direction on start.

**Wire gauge**

- The armature draws more current than the field so needs a heavier wire.
- The internal wires have very thin insulation coating and so may appear thinner.
- They also generally run much hotter than the supply cables. Using such thin conductors on the supply would melt the insulation.
- The winding resistances also help limit the current into the motor - especially during startup.
- The supply wires are heavier to reduce voltage drop between the supply and the motor.

Comment: Some DC motors have the brushes adjusted (rotated slightly) to minimise sparking at high speed. These may still run backwards, but not very well, so not recommended.

Comment: Not just sparking, probably performance as well.  Common RC car "can" motors of this sort often have a direction arrow printed on them, but similar ones sold for industrial applications could presumably not.  Also there are some types of highly optimized motors (such as little pager motors) with single-leaf brushes that are far more likely to break if run backwards.